# Проблема с заполнением таблицы QTablewidget данными из базы данных MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5, gui, qtablewidget

База данных *MySQL*, не получается отображать результат запроса в `QTablewidget`, пытаюсь сделать приложение *PyQt* отдельно от функционала, запрос выглядит так,

```py
class ConnectToMysql():
    def __int__(self):
        self.host = '172.16.18.25'
        self.user = 'admin'
        self.password = '12345'
        self.database = 'management'
        self.con = None

    def connect(self):
        self.con = pymysql.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, passwd=self.password, database=self.database)

    def get_all_data(self):
        try:
           self.connect()
           cursor = self.con.cursor(dictionary= True)
           sql = "SELECT * FROM cars"
           cursor.execute(sql)
           result = cursor.fetchall()
           return result
        except Exception as e:
            print("get data fail")
            print(e)
        finally:
            if self.con:
                self.con.close()
```

---

В приложении создал функцию, чтобы отображать полученный результат в `tablewidget`:

```py
    class Employees(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Employees, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    ## init all the widgets
        self.show_button = self.ui.show_button
        self.show_button.clicked.connect(self.show_Data)
        self.tableWidget = self.ui.tableWidget

    ## crate function
    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def show_Data(self):
        ## =============================================================================================================
        ## get all the data from database
        result = ConnectToMySQL().get_all_data_from_db()
        print(result)

        if result:
            self.result_table.setRowCount(len(result))

            for row, item in enumerate(result):
                column_1_item = QTableWidgetItem(str(item['id']))
                column_2_item = QTableWidgetItem(str(item['name']))
                column_3_item = QTableWidgetItem(str(item['surname']))
                column_4_item = QTableWidgetItem(str(item['mobile']))
                column_5_item = QTableWidgetItem(str(item['mobile']))
                column_6_item = QTableWidgetItem(str(item['carsid']))

                self.result_table.setItem(row, 0, column_1_item)
                self.result_table.setItem(row, 1, column_2_item)
                self.result_table.setItem(row, 2, column_3_item)
                self.result_table.setItem(row, 3, column_4_item)
                self.result_table.setItem(row, 4, column_5_item)
                self.result_table.setItem(row, 5, column_6_item)


        else:
            ## =========================================================================================================
            ## show some message if no data got from db
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Warning', 'No data got from database, please try again')
            return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rows = [**cursor.fetchall()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html)
>
> Метод извлекает все (или все оставшиеся) строки набора результатов запроса
> и возвращает список кортежей. 
> Если доступных строк больше нет, возвращается пустой список.

Пусть результат результат полной выборки из вашей БД `cursor.fetchall()`:

```
    self.data = [
        ('Id1', 'Name1', 'Email1', 'Phone1', 'Note1'),
        ('Id2', 'Name2', 'Email2', 'Phone2', 'Note2'),
        ('Id3', 'Name3', 'Email3', 'Phone3', 'Note3'),
        ('Id4', 'Name4', 'Email4', 'Phone4', 'Note4'),    
        ('Id5', 'Name5', 'Email5', 'Phone5', 'Note5'), 
    ]
```

Если по части выборки у вас вопросов нет,
то и в плане отображения результат запроса в `QTablewidget`
их тоже не должно быть.

Т.е. я хочу сказать, что вам надо лучше формулировать вопросы и
объязательно публиковать минимально-воспроизводимый пример,
который демонстрирует проблему.

```
import sys 
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *   
 

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.data = [
            ('Id1', 'Name1', 'Email1', 'Phone1', 'Note1'),
            ('Id2', 'Name2', 'Email2', 'Phone2', 'Note2'),
            ('Id3', 'Name3', 'Email3', 'Phone3', 'Note3'),
            ('Id4', 'Name4', 'Email4', 'Phone4', 'Note4'),    
            ('Id5', 'Name5', 'Email5', 'Phone5', 'Note5'), 
        ]        
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 5)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['Id', 'Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Note'])
        
        
        self.show_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Показать результат запроса')
        self.show_button.clicked.connect(self.on_get_data)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.show_button)
        
    def on_get_data(self):
        k = random.randint(0, len(self.data))
        result = random.SystemRandom().sample(self.data, k) # ConnectToMysql.get_all_data()
        if result:
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
            for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)

                for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, 
                        QTableWidgetItem(str(data))
                    )
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Нет данных по указанному запросу.'
            ) 
                                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(550, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S.NIK , я немного по-другому сделал ,  на консоль выводит ,  но почему-то в tablewidget  не может отображаться , выводит такую ошибку  `process finished with exit code -1073740791`

Comment: @jun66  я не понимаю что вы немного по-другому сделали, но чтобы получить реальную ошибку, запустите ваше приложение в консоли/терминале/CMD.

Comment: в вопросе выложил свой кусок кода , можете взглянуть ?  отладчик выдает такую ошибку `(<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'Employees' object has no attribute 'result_table'"), <traceback object at 0x00000298DACCBF40>)`

Comment: все , нашел ошибку ,  спасибо большое !

Comment: @jun66 а раньше код был не ваш? Чем новый код отличается от старого? Чтобы проверить ваш код - `нужен минимально-воспроизводимый пример`, который демонстрирует проблему. Для чего вы приводите первую часть кода, в которой вы делаете выборку из БД? Или у вас в этой части кода есть проблемы? Если в этой части кода проблем нет, то просто приведите пример результата этой выборки.

Comment: @jun66 пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: S.Nick,  отладчик подсказал , спасибо большое !